# html2canvas not converting svg image tags

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, html2canvas

I am using **html2canvas.js** to convert a html element with some svg tags to an image. The conversion is working fine for all the elements **except for svg image** tag as below -

```
<image y="2" transform="translate(0,0)" height="28" width="28" x="28" xlink:href="/content/adv/Control/2.png" display="block"></image>
```

Any special handling is required for svg image tags to work with html2canvas?

*Screen shot of the actual element in browser and the screenshot generated with html2canvas -*

[image: screen shot of the actual element in browser and the screenshot generated with html2canvas -]

Comment: [read more here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I went through the documentation -
> All my images are from the same origin.
> I don't have any canvas elements on the page.

What might have gone wrong?